# check if a jquery function has been already defined using the runtime notation definition

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, declaration

Good day all.

i'm starting a code review of a big project, in where the javascript code has been written by many other people than me.

I have seen, at a certain moment a functon delcared like:

```
jQuery.cookie=function(name,value,options){...}
```

so basically, someone wants to define a function called `jQuery.cookie`. Now, since I can't tolerate this, I would like at least to check if jQuery.cookie (the real library) isn't present before declare this function. In this case, does:

```
if(jQuery.cookie!== 'undefined') return true;
```

should make the trick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing typeof keyword, and quotes:

```
if(typeof jQuery.cookie !== 'undefined') return true;
```

also you can test if it is a function:

```
if(typeof jQuery.cookie !== 'function') return true;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if(typeof jQuery.cookie!== 'undefined') return true; // quote to undefined
```

Plus, are you trying to use like this?

```
if(typeof jQuery.cookie === 'undefined')
jQuery.cookie=function(name,value,options){...}
```

Comment: yes, actually is like that (added quotes I forgot to put), the problem is that I can't test the whole code, but I must put in production and hope that something doesn't smash anything... :/

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer this method because I can always relay on the  exact equality `===` regardless of the engine

```
var undefType = typeof udefined;
if(typeof jQuery.cookie !== undefType) return true;
```